# Why Break doesn't work here?

Tags: c#, function, break

I wrote a program and have one little problem.

Here, user insert number n and number k

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("n = ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("k = ");
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then i made requirement. There is main problem, break doesn't work.

```
if (k > n || k == 0 || n == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                break;
            }
```

Then, i calculated factorial

```
            int faktorijalN = 1;
            int faktorijalK = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                faktorijalN *= i;
            }
            for(int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
            {
                faktorijalK *= j;
            }
            double rez = faktorijalN / faktorijalK;
```

...and i wrote result on console

```
Console.WriteLine("n! / k! = {0}", rez);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does your execution enter the if statement and print `Error` but break isn't run? Break in this instance will just break out of the `if` statement.

Comment: Since `break` is the last statement in the `if` statement the control just comes out of the `if` block it has no meaning here.

Comment: use return instead of break.

Answer (score 1):

**Acc. to MSDN**

The break statement terminates the closest enclosing **loop or switch statement** in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx

In your case you need to `return` to move out of the function.

Comment: Thank you, i did not understand the difference between return and break :) But know i understand

Comment: @PavleDimic, if any of the answer helped you. You can mark that as Accepted

Answer (score 1):

Please use return instead of break. Also break statements are used to terminate the loop its better if you use them on switch statements.

Comment: Thank you, i did not understand the difference between return and break :) But know i understand

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return`  instead for `break`;  since there is no enclosing loop for break to continue, So the code should be like this:

```
if (k > n || k == 0 || n == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    return;
}
```

**Break :** is used for exiting from the enclosing loop, where as **return** will throws you out from the enclosing function

Comment: Thank you, i did not understand the difference between return and break :) But know i understand